# Wagtail settings only use .dev

Tags: django, deployment, environment-variables, wagtail

I do not understand how to alternate between production and dev settings. Wagtail docs do not cover it and the only wagtail tutorial I can find mentions it and then completely skips over it. There is a settings file:

```
--| settings
----| __init__.py
----| base.py
----| dev.py
----| production.py
----| .env
```

my init file:

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv

dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

ENV = os.environ.get('AMSS_ENV')

if ENV == 'dev':
    from .dev import *
elif ENV == 'prod':
    from .production import *
```

AMSS_ENV is set to 'prod'. I also have the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable set to production in the .env from a different attempt. Does the init file not fire first? is my logic broken? I get no errors and everything works but it loads in dev every time. I've tried so many other things and it just sticks like this. Can someone tell me what am I supposed to do? or where I can look?

Comment: Are you using version control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always useful to check wsgi.py and manage.py to see which settings file they are set to. It is very easy to accidentally serve or run commands with the wrong settings file by forgetting about these two files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have since learned that using the --setttings flag allows me to control which settings file is used when performing manag.py commands.